# Page views / hardware - Drupal.org

Tags: community-official-site

How many page views does drupal.org get each month? and what is the infrastructure used there?.
I found this [page](https://drupal.org/node/1280436) about the infrastructure of drupal.org.
It says that it's a relatively accurate list from September 2011.

Comment: Check out [alexa](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/drupal.org) for traffic info

Comment: Why alexa.com? it doesn't show the exact number of page views and it has no information about the infrastructure.